# Getting the percentage

Tags: javascript, percentage

I was given a problem,where I had to get the Semesteral  Grade that is : 40% of Midterm + 60% of Final. Below is the code:

```
    double Sgrade =(Mgrade * .40) +(Fgrade * .60);
```

I'm want to know, if this is the right way of getting the percentage?

Comment: Does `Sgrade` give the expected result?

Comment: yes, you can do that but correct way is `double Sgrade =(Mgrade * 40 / 100) +(Fgrade * 60 / 100);` and make sure Mgrade, Fgrade should be integer or double

Comment: `double Sgrade` is not JavaScript.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please see comments for explanation. Also side note I have renamed your variables using camelCase

```js
let mGrade = 50 //assumes this is already a percent, otherwise you will need to convert percentage = (grade/total)*100;
let fGrade = 50 // assumes this is already a percent,, otherwise you will need to convert percentage = (grade/total)*100;
let sGrade = (mGrade*40/100) + (fGrade*60/100)

//percentage = (grade/total)*100;
console.log(sGrade);
```